# How to create a dataclass with optional fields that outputs field in json only if the field is not None

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I am unclear about how to use a @dataclass to convert a mongo doc into a python dataclass. With my NSQL documents they may or may not contain some of the fields. I only want to output a field (using asdict) from the dataclass if that field was present in the mongo document.

Is there a way to create a field that will be output with dataclasses.asdict only if it exists in the mongo doc?

I have tried using **post_init** but have not figured out a solution.

```
# in this example I want to output the 'author' field ONLY if it is present in the mongo document
@dataclass
class StoryTitle:
    _id: str 
    title: str
    author: InitVar[str] = None
    dateOfPub: int = None

    def __post_init__(self, author):
        print(f'__post_init__ got called....with {author}')
        if author is not None:
            self.newauthor = author
            print(f'self.author is now {self.newauthor}')

# foo and bar approximate documents in mongodb
foo = dict(_id='b23435xx3e4qq', title = 'goldielocks and the big bears', author='mary', dateOfPub = 220415)

newFoo = StoryTitle(**foo)
json_foo = json.dumps(asdict(newFoo))
print(json_foo)

bar = dict(_id='b23435xx3e4qq', title = 'War and Peace', dateOfPub = 220415)
newBar = StoryTitle(**bar)
json_bar = json.dumps(asdict(newBar))
print(json_bar)
```

My output json does not (of course) have the 'author' field. Anyone know how to accomplish this? I suppose I could just create my own asdict method ...

Answer (score 3):

The `dataclasses.asdict` helper function doesn't offer a way to exclude fields with default or *un-initialized* values unfortunately -- however, the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library does.

The `dataclass-wizard` is a *(de)serialization* library I've created, which is built on top of `dataclasses` module. It adds no extra dependencies outside of stdlib, only the [`typing-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module for compatibility reasons with earlier Python versions.

To skip dataclass fields with default or un-initialized values in serialization for ex. with `asdict`, the `dataclass-wizard` provides the [`skip_defaults`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#skip-defaults) option. **However**, there is also a minor issue I noted with your code above. If we set a default for the author field as `None`, that means that we won't be able to distinguish between `null` values and also the case when `author` field is not present when de-serializing the json data.

So in below example, I've created a `CustomNull` object similar to the `None` singleton in python. The name and implementation doesn't matter overmuch, however in our case we use it as a sentinel object to determine if a value for `author` is passed in or not. If it is not present in the input data when `from_dict` is called, then we simply exclude it when serializing data with `to_dict` or `asdict`, as shown below.

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # can be removed in Python 3.10+

from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


# create our own custom `NoneType` class
class CustomNullType:
    # these methods are not really needed, but useful to have.
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<null>'

    def __bool__(self):
        return False


# this is analogous to the builtin `None = NoneType()`
CustomNull = CustomNullType()


# in this example I want to output the 'author' field ONLY if it is present in the mongo document
@dataclass
class StoryTitle(JSONWizard):

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        # skip default values for dataclass fields when `to_dict` is called
        skip_defaults = True

    _id: str
    title: str
    # note: we could also define it like
    #  author: str | None = None
    # however, using that approach we won't know if the value is
    # populated as a `null` when de-serializing the json data.
    author: str | None = CustomNull
    # by default, the `dataclass-wizard` library uses regex to case transform
    # json fields to snake case, and caches the field name for next time.
    # dateOfPub: int = None
    date_of_pub: int = None


# foo and bar approximate documents in mongodb
foo = dict(_id='b23435xx3e4qq', title='goldielocks and the big bears', author='mary', dateOfPub=220415)

new_foo = StoryTitle.from_dict(foo)
json_foo = new_foo.to_json()
print(json_foo)

bar = dict(_id='b23435xx3e4qq', title='War and Peace', dateOfPub=220415)
new_bar = StoryTitle.from_dict(bar)
json_bar = new_bar.to_json()
print(json_bar)

# lastly, we try de-serializing with `author=null`. the `author` field should still
# be populated when serializing the instance, as it was present in input data.
bar = dict(_id='b23435xx3e4qq', title='War and Peace', dateOfPub=220415, author=None)
new_bar = StoryTitle.from_dict(bar)
json_bar = new_bar.to_json()
print(json_bar)
```

Output:

```
{"_id": "b23435xx3e4qq", "title": "goldielocks and the big bears", "author": "mary", "dateOfPub": 220415}
{"_id": "b23435xx3e4qq", "title": "War and Peace", "dateOfPub": 220415}
{"_id": "b23435xx3e4qq", "title": "War and Peace", "author": null, "dateOfPub": 220415}
```

---

*Note:* the `dataclass-wizard` can be installed with `pip`:

```
$ pip install dataclass-wizard
```